# What is the value range of summary(lm) Multiple R^2?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, r-squared

I have the summary of a linear model in R:

```
Call:
lm(formula = deceased ~ `0s` + `10s` + `20s` + `30s` + `40s` + 
    `50s` + `60s` + `70s` + `80s`, data = combined_dt)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         `0s`        `10s`        `20s`        `30s`        `40s`        `50s`        `60s`        `70s`        `80s`  
   -91.9495       3.2929      -0.6740       0.3103      -0.2378       0.1701      -0.2676       0.1459      -0.7538       0.4998  


Call:
lm(formula = deceased ~ `0s` + `10s` + `20s` + `30s` + `40s` + 
    `50s` + `60s` + `70s` + `80s`, data = combined_dt)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-26.5670  -6.0518   0.2351   6.5129  24.9963 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -91.94946   46.26820  -1.987 0.049350 *  
`0s`          3.29289    0.56858   5.791 6.60e-08 ***
`10s`        -0.67402    0.18351  -3.673 0.000371 ***
`20s`         0.31030    0.03884   7.989 1.39e-12 ***
`30s`        -0.23781    0.12482  -1.905 0.059338 .  
`40s`         0.17015    0.17934   0.949 0.344810    
`50s`        -0.26763    0.12272  -2.181 0.031305 *  
`60s`         0.14591    0.16661   0.876 0.383057    
`70s`        -0.75379    0.26970  -2.795 0.006118 ** 
`80s`         0.49978    0.06144   8.134 6.56e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 9.688 on 111 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9861,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.985 
F-statistic: 877.7 on 9 and 111 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Is my R^2 just really awesome and 98.61% or is it really bad and 0.9861%.

As far as i understood it, R^2 is basically the percentage of the variance explained by the linear model, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R^2$ is pretty much always reported on a $[0,1]$ interval, so yours is very high. High $R^2$ means that much of the variability in your data is explained by the model, so a strong fit of the model to your data.

This does not necessarily mean a generalizable model on unseen data, though your high adjusted $R^2$ has me optimistic that your model would generalize fairly well and is not just playing connect-the-dots with the data on which you for the model, the term for which is “overfitting”.

Comment: Ah, perfect, thank you. Only after 10 minutes,  can i accept it as the answer, sry :-)